# Pop up message in CSS/HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically i have a map, and i want to make that when i hover on one of the states to get a popup message that shows the name of the state. This is what i have done so far: (this is just part of the code)

```
var states = map.selectAll('path.state') 
.data(states.features)
    .enter().append('path')
    .attr('class', 'state')
    .attr('id', function(d) {console.log(d);return d.id;})
    .attr('d', path)
    .attr("stroke","white")
    .attr("stroke-width",2)
    .attr('fill', 'lightgreen')
    .on("mousemove",fnk)
    .on("mouseout",fnk2)
```

When function "`fnk()`" gets called (on `mousemove`) it basically highlights the state in green color and it stores name of the state in variable "`dsa`".

```
function fnk() {
asd = d3.select(this).style("fill","green");
dsa = asd.data()[0].properties.gn_name;}
```

Now what i want to make is that that data in variable `dsa` is shown to a user in some kind of pop up message or some rectangle element that is active while mouse is placed on a state. I tried with "alert" but then a user needs to click "OK" button to remove the message and i want message to fade away by itself.

Comment: You might want to add more information about what map provider and/or jQuery plugins you are using. Map providers like OpenStreetMap/OpenLayers or Google Maps typically offer the ability to create popups/info windows in their respective APIs, but they do it in different ways. As arbitrarily chosen examples, see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple for Google Maps and http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/osm-marker-popup.html / http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/osm-marker-popup.js for OpenLayers.

Comment: (Didn't fit in previous comment). Additionally, there are jQuery plugins that you can use for more generic plugins. This arbitrarily chosen site (http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-popup-window-image-slider-plugins/) lists some of them, but I didn't check how current that selection is.

Comment: Im using json file that contains all requiered coordinates for the map to be created. I'm just trying to find a way how to append a rectangle with state name inside of it when mouse is moved on one of the states.

Comment: But where does the *map* come from? If you are using the services of OpenStreetMaps, Google Maps, Bing Maps or such, you can do what you want using the respective providers API.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a number of divs to use as pop-up elements, position them above each state, and set its css

```
visibility: hidden
```

And then inside fnk

```
<"your pop-up element">.style("visibility", "hidden")
```

And of course, do the opposite in fnk2

```
.style("visibility", "visible")
```

I don't know much about DOM handling in JS, but that's really archaic anyway.

You should really look into JQuery, you can make stuff fade in and fade out prettier (instead of just disappearing and appearing like the code I posted). Not to mention, it takes less code and is more portable across browsers.

Comment: Yeah but that would mean i have to create XY amount of divs, and the name of the state is placed in a variable when you hover over the state. I'm just trying to find a way to show variable data in a rectangle that is active when mouse is hovering over specific state.

Comment: JavaScript only has confirm, prompt and alert dialog boxes and all 3 require a button press, so if you're looking for a one-liner JS solution, you're out of luck.